# Appropriate ways of storing records across whole program?

Tags: c#, json, api

I am creating a C# forms application using Visual Studio that communicates with a server using an API.

1. I have successfully retrieved a Json string from the server and parsed the data into easily accessable properties.

```
///elsewhere in program
var jsonparams = JsonParam.DesJson(jsonString);
///

public partial class JsonParam
{
   public List<InsideData> data { get; set; }
   public string errmsg { get; set; }
   public int status { get; set; }
   public int ts { get; set; }
}
public partial class InsideData
{
   public string access_token { get; set; } = "";
   public string alias { get; set; }
   public string uid {get; set;}
   //etc etc
}
public partial class JsonParam
{
   public static JsonParam DesJson(string jsonString) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonParam>(jsonString);
}
```

2. I have printed out "alias" in a comboBox using:

```
foreach (var a in jsonParam.data)
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(a.alias);
}
```

This works correctly, however, I then repeat 1 & 2 several times for several different jsonStrings. This gives me several "alias" entries in the comboBox.

My next step is to select an "alias" from the comboBox and print out the "uid" that was previously parsed from the jsonString, But of course since I recalled my JsonParam function several times (to get more "alias" entries), the saved "uid" entries from the previous "alias" entries have been lost.

What is the best way to save all the data in "InsideData" everytime I parse a jsonString so that I can access the data later?

kind of like:
jsonString1.alias
jsonString2.alias

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
foreach (var a in jsonParam.data)
{
   comboBox1.Items.Add(a.alias);
}
```

for this:

```
foreach (var a in jsonParam.data)
{
   ComboboxItem item = new ComboboxItem();
   item.Text = a.alias;
   item.Value = a.uid;
   comboBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```